# What is the most efficient way to handle multiple conditions that are picked from the user?

Tags: c#

I am building a scraper in C# and the user wants to be able to type down multiple conditions:

- Person name
- Age
- AND/OR statement

We get the persons from the web page and compare their age to the age inputted from the user.

Here is an example of what the final condition could look like:

```
if((person1.age == AgeTextBox1.Text && person2.age== AgeTextBox2.Text) || ( person1.age = AgeTextBox1.Text && person3.age== AgeTextBox3.Text && person2.age== AgeTextBox2.Text))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

And he wants to be able to use up to 10 different years.

The only idea that comes to my mind is to use a lot of `TextBox` and `CheckBox` controls and then handle every possible outcome with `if-else if` statements, but that seems ridiculous as it would require A LOT of `if` statements.

**What is the best way to handle all possible conditions?**

Comment: What those all numbers mean?

Comment: I can't understand you. Can you specify - The expected behaviour? A minimal code to reproduce the issue? A clear problem description maybe?

Comment: The user selects a year and a value that must match the year's value in the web page that is going to be scraped. Is there a better way to handle every possible condition other than using ton of `if` statements

Comment: A value that must match the year's value?! What does that mean? How does 2014 ever equal 300?

Comment: Edited with another (hopefully easier to understand) example

Comment: Have a look at the CheckedListBox!

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to dynamically add your `TextBox`es (or a better way to create user control) when the user press an "`Add`" button. And then track them while creating, in a `List<>` and then the user pressed a button, loop in the `List` and retrieve all their `Text` one by one. No need to add them in design-time.

Answer (score 0):

What about operator precedence and nesting ? The only decent solution is to have a tree of conditions and operators and dynamically append condition and operator nodes. "UI" sample:

```
[Conditions]
[Add AND] [Add OR] [Add Condition] [Remove selected node]
AND
  Age equals 100
  OR
    Name equals "Foo"
    Name equals "Bar"
```

Code will be something like

```
public class Node {
  public virtual bool Evaluate(Person p);
}

public class AndNode : Node {
  public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }

  public override bool Evaluate(Person p) {
    foreach(var node in Children) {
      if (!node.Evaluate(person))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}

public class AgeNode : Node {
  public int Value { get; set; }
  public override bool Evaluate(Person p) {
    return p.Age == Value;
  }
}

... etc
```